# Add All Existing Projects Within Directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio, project

I realize that this is not the best practices for working on individual projects. However, I had a rather large code base I am attempting to refactor, and would like to know if a change I make has modified/broken any number of existing projects.

Is there a way to add all existing projects within a specific directory to a single solution within visual studio?

If not, is there another way I could do this without manually adding each project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe there is a method in the box.

But if it's really going to be that tedious of a task I would use PowerShell to [search the directory for a files with the csproj extension](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/ezine/ezine133.htm), and output a bunch of ["Project" statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165951%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (along with generation of unique identifiers) that you can copy/paste into your Solution file.